# creating and editing many objects at the same time

Tags: r, loops, object

I have a model object `m1`. I need to create 100 distinctly named copies so I can adjust and plot each. To create a copy, I currently do this as such:

```
m1recip1 <- m1
m1recip2 <- m1
m1recip3 <- m1
m1recip4 <- m1
m1recip5 <- m1
m1recip6 <- m1
m1recip7 <- m1
...
m1recip100 <- m1
```

I planned to create these through a loop, but this is less efficient because I only know how to do so by initializing all 100 objects before looping through them. I'm effectively looking for something similar to the macro facility in other languages (where m1recip&i would produce the names iteratively). I'm sure R can do this - how?

Comment: Spawning objects in a loop is usually considered bad practice. Try using built-in R data structures made specifically for this purpose, specifically, data frames

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914568/r-create-variables-in-loop

Comment: Instead of creating 100 objects in your environment, create a list with 100 elements like: `m1recip_list <- lapply(1:100, function(x) m1)`

Comment: If you go this route, please try to be aware that any frustration you encounter about "how hard this seems to be in R compared to other languages" is likely because this sort of thing is generally done much more efficiently using other data structures (lists) or a function.

Comment: @user3470883 not really - those variables already exist, so the winning solution doesn't get me there (mget() breaks because the var_names made through paste don't exist to be put into a list...)...but it looks like some related suggestions are getting me there. Thanks!

Comment: @joran - I'm happy to take any route, no frustration at all; just trying to make it clear to myself what I wanted and how I was currently thinking through it to get feedback. Lists and apply functions are perfect - thank you!

Comment: @avid_useR - thanks! Feel free to paste your comment as an answer so I can "accept" it, this is exactly what I needed (whoops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning `m1` to 100 objects, we can create a list with 100 elements like the following:

```
m1recip_list <- lapply(1:100, function(x) m1)
```

We can then reference each element by element number `m1recip_list[[10]]` or apply a function to every element of the list using `lapply`:

```
lapply(m1recip_list, some_function)
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, reconsider saving many similar structured objects in global environment. Instead, use a named list which results in the maintenance of **one**, indexed object to maintain where R has many handlers (i.e., apply family) to run operations across all elements.

Specifically, consider `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply`) to build the 100 *m1* elements and use `setNames` to name them accordingly. You lose no functionality of object if saved within a list.

```
model_list <- setNames(replicate(100, m1, simplify = FALSE),
                       paste0("m1recip", 1:100))

model_list$m1recip1
model_list$m1recip2
model_list$m1recip3
...
```

Comment: thanks for making the reasoning behind this so clear

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create object names using the paste function in a loop, and you can assign them values using the assign function as opposed to the "<-" operator.

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  assign(paste("m1recip",i, sep = ""), m1)
}
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.