# Creating data frames dynamically using items of loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a for loop as

```
for(i in c("a","b","c","d"))
{
    as.name(paste("df",i,sep=""))= mydataframe
}
```

`mydataframe` is a data frame and I want to create data frames `dfa`,`dfb`,`dfc` and `dfd` using this loop.

The `as.name(paste("df",i,sep=""))` does not work here. I do not want to create a list that has the 4 data frames.

Can I directly create 4 data frames from this loop?

Comment: This is a bad design pattern in R. It's better to work with a [list of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames). You can much more easily work with data in a list rather than creating a bunch of similarly named variables in your global environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914568/r-create-variables-in-loop

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `assign`. Although in general, you are better off using lists.

Using your example:

```
for(i in letters[1:4]){
  assign(paste0("df", i), mydataframe)
}
```

Note that this will simply create the same object 4 times, unless you change what `mydataframe` is inside the loop.